# The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection threw an exception.)

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

My work environment is
1. VS 2012
2. Oracle 11
3. Oracle 12 installed in C and D drives.
 at oracleConnection step i'm getting
 The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception.
and i added path in Environment variables like **D:\app\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin**
and we are using **tnsnames**

Comment: Do you have 3 different Oracle Clients installed on your machine? How does your `PATH` environment variable looks like? For `PATH` you have "First come - first served", so you may change the order of folders. Anyway, I don't see any reason to have more than just one Oracle client (i.e. one each for 32-bit and 64-bit) installed on a machine.

Comment: The machine was given to me with already installed version Oracle 11 and later i installed 12 ,First i installed it in C drive but our framework recommends D drive so i again installed it in D drive also and all are 32-bit versions only, my machine is 64-bit. @Wernfried Domscheit

Comment: Then first I would recommend to uninstall all of them apart from the one you actually need.

Comment: yes finally it's working, i uninstall all of them except version 11. There is a folder like deinstall in that we need to run a batch file as an Administrator and it will ask inventory path of same installed directory if we provide it and say yes then it will remove that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your in Windows?

Always try the connection in the [Windows OLE DB Connection manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/ole-db-connection-manager?view=sql-server-2017) first, to check if the installation is working.

You can find it via Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools\ODBC Data Sources.

Make sure to use the same bitness (32 or 64) as the installed drivers.

Comment: i didn't found any drivers for Oracle version 11, but i found for Version 12 and now i need to use version 11 only @Rob Bos

Comment: Ok, Did you check to see if you can setup a working connection via something else then? If i recall correctly, there is also something like tnsping that can be used to test.